# Silverlight CMS

Tags: silverlight, content-management-system, integration

I am have started working with Silverlight and thought I would make a full futured website with a Silverlight front and are therefor looking for an Open Source CMS that takes care of the administration part and lets me worry about the presentation.

This is a hobby project so I am not very intrested in spending any money on this.
I have started to look into N2 Cms which is very cool but still is the a better suited framework for my task?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My opinion for what it's worth is that any already praised CMS will work as a backend for your project.

For example, if you knew [Drupal](http://drupal.org) rather well, you would be interested in [Connecting Drupal And Silverlight](http://mattserbinski.com/blog/connecting-drupal-and-silverlight). I'm sure Google will get you equivalent blog or forum posts explaining how to do a [Joomla](http://joomla.org) or [MODx](http://modxcms.com/) integration. (or pick your favorite CMS)

Imho, there is no need to invest money, however you'll have to invest time in understanding the CMS you decided to use as a backend.

Answer (score 1):

I've built such CMS based on :
     - Silverlight 4
     - Prism 4 / WS / WCF / 
     - the model is store on SQL Serveur 2008 or 2008 R2
     - User administration based on ASP.Net framework allowing 
                     - Integrated Windows Acces
                     - Ananymous Acces
                     - Form ACCES via ASP.Net security DB
     - Fonctionalities :
          - Nanage User Access
          - Manage Navigation
          - Manage Data Acces (in order to navigate into your Data)
          - Built sofisticated UI "viewParts" without any code
          - Build your own components to interact with existings
          - ...
      - I'm currently configurating a demo that should be available next days in http://demo.selfcockpit.com

```
   - The market strategy has not been defined yet.

   Best regards.
          Christophe
```